# Typescript: using conditional typing in conditional statements

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-types

Assume I have some a-lot-of-union type:

```js
var MyComplexType = MyType1 | MyType2 | MyType3 | ... | MyTypeN
```

where `MyType{N}` has this kind of signature:

```js
type MyType1 = {
    type: string,
    data: <different data for different types>
}
```

I know that I can use a kind of type guard function, e. g.:

```js
function isMyComplexTypeOfMyType1(item: MyComplexType): item is MyType1 {
    return item.type == "type of MyType1"
}
```

but in this case I should write a lot of this kind of functions.

So, the question is: can I dynamically define type inside a conditional statements (`if ... else` or `switch ... case`)? For example:

```js
function someFunction(item: MyComplexType) {
    switch (item.type) {
        case "type of MyType1":
            // item is MyType1
            // do something
            break
        case "type of MyType2":
            // item is MyType2
            // do something
            break
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to check a union-typed value with a `switch/case` statement, you should probably make it a [disciminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) where the `type` property of each constituent of the union is declared to be the relevant [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) instead of just `string`.  You don't really need conditional types to deal with this, at least not inside your `someFunction()` implementation.

For example, let's say your types look like this:

```
type MyType1 = { type: "type1", data: { a: string, b: number } };
type MyType2 = { type: "type2", data: { c: boolean, d: string } };
type MyType3 = { type: "type3", data: { e: number, f: boolean } };

type MyComplexType = MyType1 | MyType2 | MyType3;
```

Then the compiler will automatically treat checks on `MyComplexType["type"]` as a type guard, like this:

```
const exhaustivenessCheck = (x: never) => x;

function someFunction(item: MyComplexType) {
    switch (item.type) {
        case "type1":
            console.log(2 * item.data.b); // okay
            break;
        case "type2":
            console.log(item.data.d.charAt(0)); // okay
            break;
        case "type3":
            console.log(7 - item.data.e); // okay
            break;
        default:
            throw exhaustivenessCheck(item); // okay
    }
}
```

That `exhaustivenessCheck()` is basically a `throw` statement if the function somehow falls through to `default`.  That shouldn't happen, but the usefulness is that the compiler will warn you if it doesn't think you checked everything.  That's because `exhaustivenessCheck()` requires its parameter to be of type `never`, which can't happen.  If you comment out the `case "type3"` clause, or sometime later add a new constituent to the `MyComplexType` union, the `exhaustivenessCheck()` line will throw an error saying you failed to check a case.

---

At this point you could stop, but if your types are really that programmatic in that they contain just two properties, a `type` discriminant string and a `data` property, then you can define your types with less repetition like this:

```
// a mapping from type string to data type
type MyTypes = {
    type1: { a: string, b: number };
    type2: { c: boolean, d: string };
    type3: { e: number, f: boolean };
}

// convert the mapping to the union of types
type MyType<K extends keyof MyTypes = keyof MyTypes> = {
    [P in K]: { type: P, data: MyTypes[P] }
}[K]
```

You can verify that `MyType` or `MyType<keyof MyTypes>` expands to the `MyComplexType` union I defined above.  Your old `MyType1` is now `MyType<"type1">`, and so forth.  That is, if you need to use your old names for the types you can do it like this:

```
type MyType1 = MyType<"type1">;
type MyType2 = MyType<"type2">;
type MyType3 = MyType<"type3">
type MyComplexType = MyType;
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Awesome, this definetely helped! Both of approaches are usable for me, thank you a lot!