# Using conditional Typescript types for a turnery operation in a funciton

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I'm having a huge amount of difficulty trying to understand conditional types in Typescript. None of the examples I've seen so far seem to explain how to work around the problem I'm trying to solve.

I've created this reduced test case of what I'm trying to do. Basically if I am targeting a 24 hour slot, I want to assign a valid 24 hour time. If I'm targeting the 12 hour slot, I want to assign a valid 12 hour time. Typescript isn't allowing this though.

```
// The basic goal I'm trying to achieve

type Hrs12 = 12 | 1 // All valid 12 hour times
type Hrs24 = 12 | 13 // All valid 24 hour times

interface Hours {
    hrs12: Hrs12
    hrs24: Hrs24
}

const doStuff = (hoursObj: Hours, target: 'hrs24' | 'hrs12') => {
    // Error: Type '1 | 13' is not assignable to type '12'.
    // Error: Type '1' is not assignable to type '12'. ts(2322)
    hoursObj[target] = target === 'hrs24' ? 13 : 1
}

doStuff({ hrs24: 12, hrs12: 12 }, 'hrs12')
```

So far this is my best attempt at trying to use conditional types (I know it's wrong):

```
// This doesn't work

type Hrs12 = 12 | 1 // All valid 12 hour times
type Hrs24 = 12 | 13 // All valid 24 hour times

interface Hours {
    hrs12: Hrs12
    hrs24: Hrs24
}

const doStuff = <T>(hoursObj: Hours, target: 'hrs24' | 'hrs12') => {
    type Hrs = T extends Hrs12 ? Hrs12 : Hrs24
    hoursObj[target] = <Hrs>(target === 'hrs24' ? 13 : 1)
}

doStuff<Hrs12>({ hrs24: 12, hrs12: 12 }, 'hrs12')
```

I've seen these two questions:

- [Typescript: using conditional typing in conditional statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046822/typescript-using-conditional-typing-in-conditional-statements)
- [Conditional types with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175508/conditional-types-with-typescript)

The best I could glean from those was that I can split it out in a switch statement but I really want to avoid doing repetative stuff like `hoursObj.hrs12 = 1`, `hoursObj.hrs24 = 13`

```
// This works but surely there is a better way?

const doStuff = (hoursObj: Hours, target: 'hrs24' | 'hrs12') => {
    switch (target) {
        case 'hrs12':
            hoursObj.hrs12 = 1
            break
        case 'hrs24':
            hoursObj.hrs24 = 13
            break
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch is a decent option. If you want to go the generic route, you can do it, but unresolved generic types will usually end up requiring an assertion somewhere since something like `hoursObj[target] = (target === 'hrs24' ? 13 : 1)` is not sound:

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=53&pln=12&pc=5#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdQCYHsCmsB2ByALqA7kgE4DWAUKdgJ4AOKoAEobAIwBMoAvKG6AD7egQoAIIAbUaABuAQ1HQE3dpCQBXQqGzQAtmgo06jWKwAsnRX24BmQWDESZchSdDK1G7btLR02FIQBm0gDGBqpMoADepKAxLkxsAFwM8azRsZBMJkmGJqQAvuRBSOiwuMgAytgq-v5mADzgoCgAHr7oCPCYGUbGmBZdKZgAfAAUrkwA8gBGAFbZYbAANBrShADmKNhJ4ACUnEORaTHjsNMzANrYqxvYALpmI1frm5wcXAM9fQD8VqBJzHtpPB6AtzuBbvlyBUqjURhE4j1-qxlt1EuY8ssPmxMDsgA

Comment: That is looking a lot like the sort of thing that I'm after @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. Mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@TitianCernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) I was able to get my use case to work

He posted the answer in this [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=43&pln=3&pc=1#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdQCYHsCmsB2ByALqA7kgE4DWAUKdgJ4AOKoAEobAIwBMoAvKG6AD7egQoAIIAbUaABuAQ1HQE3dpCQBXQqGzQAtmgo06jWKwAsnRX24BmQWDESZchSdDK1G7btLR02FIQBm0gDGBqpMoADepKAxLkxsAFwM8azRsZBMJkmGJqQAvuRBSOiwuMgAytgq-v5mADzgoCgAHr7oCPCYGUbGmBZdKZgAfAAUrkwA8gBGAFbZYbAANBrShADmKNhJ4ACUnEORaTHjsNMzANrYqxvYALpmI1frm5wcXAM9fQD8VqBJzHtpPB6AtzuBbvlyBUqjURhE4j1-qxlt1EuY8ssPmxMDsgA)

I've modified it slightly and added comments to clarify some things

```
// Verbose fully commented example

type Hrs12 = 12 | 1 // All valid 12 hour times
type Hrs24 = 12 | 13 // All valid 24 hour times

interface Hours {
    hrs12: Hrs12
    hrs24: Hrs24
}

function doStuff
    // TypeName is now accessible from inside the function
    // TypeName can be used anywhere 'hrs24' or 'hrs12' can be used
    // TypeName does not need to be called "TypeName"
    <TypeName extends 'hrs24' | 'hrs12'>
    (
        hoursObj: Hours,
        // The variable that you use as the selector needs to be typed as TypeName
        target: TypeName
    ) {
    hoursObj[target] =
        // This line assigns the Hours[TypeName] type to the result of the Turnery operation
        // Think of Hours[TypeName] here as the same sort of thing you would see in regular JavaScript
        // "TypeName" is dynamically selecting the type from the "Hours" interface based on what the value of "TypeName" is
        <Hours[TypeName]>(target === 'hrs24' ? 13 : 1)
}

doStuff({ hrs24: 12, hrs12: 12 }, 'hrs12')
```

That example looks way more complex than it really is.

Here it is again but with all the comments removed and `TypeName` shortened to `T`:

```
// Clean version

type Hrs12 = 12 | 1 // All valid 12 hour times
type Hrs24 = 12 | 13 // All valid 24 hour times

interface Hours {
    hrs12: Hrs12
    hrs24: Hrs24
}

function doStuff<T extends 'hrs24' | 'hrs12'>( hoursObj: Hours, target: T) {
    hoursObj[target] = <Hours[T]>(target === 'hrs24' ? 13 : 1)
}

doStuff({ hrs24: 12, hrs12: 12 }, 'hrs12')
```

Also, here is an example of how to apply more than one of these calculated types

```
// Example of applying more than one calculated type

type Hrs12 = 12 | 1 // All valid 12 hour times
type Hrs24 = 12 | 13 // All valid 24 hour times

interface Hours {
    hrs12: Hrs12
    hrs24: Hrs24
}

interface Other {
    one: 1 | 10
    two: 2 | 20
}

function doStuff <T extends 'hrs24' | 'hrs12', T2 extends 'one' | 'two'> (
    hoursObj: Hours,
    target: T,
    other: Other,
    otherTarget: T2
) {

    hoursObj[target] = <Hours[T]>(target === 'hrs24' ? 13 : 1)
    other[otherTarget] = <Other[T2]>(otherTarget === 'one' ? 10 : 20)
}

doStuff({ hrs24: 12, hrs12: 12 }, 'hrs12', { one: 1, two: 2 }, 'one')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `doStuff` to be this and it will compile:

```
const doStuff = (hoursObj: Hours, target: 'hrs24' | 'hrs12') => {
  if (target === 'hrs24') {
    hoursObj[target] = 13;
  } else {
    hoursObj[target] = 1;
  }
};
```

The problem with the original attempt is that the compiler does not know the type of `hoursObj[target]` when it first parses that expression. It is not sophisticated enough to back track the additional type knowledge when parsing the `target === 'hrs24' ? 13 : 1` expression.

The suggested change above uses something called a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to narrow the type of `hoursObj[target]` in the if and else blocks. The original suggestion does not use a type guard and so the compiler cannot determine the final type of `hoursObj[target]`.

If you wanted to get fancier, you could create a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) and make the type guard more complex. In this particular situation, the creating a user-defined type guard is a bit silly, but in a production setting, this could come in handy:

```
const doStuff = (hoursObj: Hours, target: 'hrs24' | 'hrs12') => {
  if (isHours24(target)) {
    hoursObj[target] = 13;
  } else {
    hoursObj[target] = 1;
  }
};

function isHours24(target: 'hrs24' | 'hrs12'): target is 'hrs24' {
  return target === 'hrs24';
}
```

The `target is 'hrs24'` asserts the type of target and ensures its type after any conditional.

Comment: Thanks but this is not really the answer that I'm after. I'm trying to understand conditional types in Typescript better. The solution you have posted is basically the same as the switch statement I posted in the question but slightly neater. I'm looking for a method that uses conditional types if that's possible.